Can Ed25519 signature be used as a base for ChaCha20 secret key?
We'd like to distribute a container which is encrypted using ChaCha20 and signed using Ed25519.
The Ed25519 secret key (SK) is distributed among a small number of trusted people who are called "writers".
The public key (PK) together with a signature SIGN(PK, with: SK) is then distributed among people whom we call "readers".
The goal is that these two secrets (SK and (PK, SIGN(PK, with: SK))) are small and can be distributed as, say, URLs.
To create a container, a writer first encrypts plain text data using HASH(SIGN(PK, with: SK)) (with Blake3 being the hash function) as a KEY for the ChaCha20 cipher and then signs it using SK. The signature of the container (SIGN(<CONTAINER-CONTENT>, with: SK)) is distributed together with the container.
When a reader receives the container with it's signature, assuming they also have the (PK, SIGN(PK, with: SK)) pair, they

verify the container's signature using PK
verify that the SIGN(PK, with: SK) is valid in a sense that it generates a valid KEY in the next step
use HASH(SIGN(PK, with: SK)) as a KEY to decrypt the container

My question is whether this is approach makes sense and is cryptographically secure.
My main worry, but please suggest others, is that the ChaCha20 encryption/decryption key is 256 bits long which I presume means security target 2^256(?). Whereas, while the signature is 512 bits, it's security target is 2^128. So I'm not sure whether the signature is "random enough" to be used as the base for deriving the encryption/decryption key.
One other approach we have in mind is to distribute the triple (PK, KEY, SIGN(KEY, with: SK) to the readers, but would like to avoid that if possible due to the added length.
Or perhaps there are already existing schemes for just this purpose?

I'm afraid that this is a perfect example of an X - Y problem. Hashing cannot be used for encryption / decryption. Signatures are usually not considered secret. URL's are not considered secure either, although it is of course possible to include a secret into a URL as parameter and send it over a secure channel. As it is stated the question doesn't seem to adhere to the usual terminology and, tbh, the difference in size is the least of your worries.

"Hashing cannot be used for encryption / decryption": it's not, it's used to generate the ChaCha20 secret key, but I could have misunderstood you message. "URL's are not considered secure": yes, in this case they're meant to be sent over a secure channel. I only mentioned URLs to hint why short size is desired, there are other reasons, but I didn't want to go too much off tangent. "the question doesn't seem to adhere to the usual terminology": help in improving the question would be highly appreciated.

OK, so the hash is used as a KDF and the encryption method is not specified but considered secure? Because I don't get that from "first encrypts it using HASH(SIGN(PK, with: SK))"...

"Because I don't get that from": Ah I see where I was being confusing. Hope I get it better this time: Yes, the HASH(SIGN(PK, with: SK)) derives/generates a key which is then passed to the ChaCha20 stream cipher. Similarly as is done in this example.

What's the goal of this construction? Is it to enforce a separation between the capability of the writer and readers(writers can read/write, readers can only read), ensure integrity(only writers can create valid containers), and prevent anyone else from interacting(ie either reading plaintext container content or forging a valid container)? I assume you already prevent someone from rolling back the container to a previous valid state without being an authorized writer.

@oaky_0ffc "Is it to ...": yes, that is it. "I assume you already prevent someone from rolling back the container to a previous valid state without being an authorized writer.": Also yes, the containers also contain a plain text version vector which is also signed.

Yeah, this is an X-Y problem then. Here's an alternative idea:
During setup, we create a 64 byte secret S_m. We then split the secret into two 32 byte subsecrets S_msig and S_enc. One of them (S_msig) is used as the input to the signature scheme setup(ie it outputs a public and private key(Pub and Priv)). The other is the encryption key. Writers get Priv, Pub, and S_enc. They use AEAD with S_enc as the key and commit Pub as part of the AD. Sign the AEAD ciphertext using Priv. Readers get Pub and S_enc. They verify the signature using Pub and then decrypt using S_enc.

@oaky_0ffc The alternative looks good, thanks. I'd be happy to mark it as an answer. Small aside, what does the "m" in "S_msig" stand for?

Secret_Master_Signature, ie the master secret that determines the signature's parameters(ie the generated public and private keys).
I'll write up the answer real quick then. Thanks for confirming your goal.

So, the OP's goal here with the construction in the question is to do the following:

Prevent anyone from creating a valid container without being a writer(ie possesing the writer's secrets).*
Allow the readers to verify the integrity of the container and decrypt the container's contents.*
Prevent anyone else from reading the container contents or feeding invalid/tampered container data without detection.*

First of all, the scheme above will not work cryptographically. A signature is not intended to be secure key material and can not be used as such. A signature's public parameters(ie the public key) is also not generally intended to be used as secure key material**.
Let's get into a different scheme that makes more sense.

Let Random(n) -> r be a secure uniformly random source that returns the specified n bytes as an array.
Let Encrypt(a, p, k) -> (c, t) be a secure AEAD encryption function that takes additional data(a), the plaintext(p), and a secure uniformly random key(k) and outputs the encrypted ciphertext(c) and an authentication tag(t). This function handles generation of the needed nonce/IV securely. See details for your specific AEAD function for more information.
Let Decrypt(a, c, t, k) -> (p) || ERROR be a secure AEAD decryption function that takes the additional data(a), the ciphertext(c), the authentication tag(t), and a secure uniformly random key(k) and either releases the valid plaintext(p) or outputs ERROR and does not release anything
Let Signature_setup(r) -> (s, v) be a function that generates in a secure signature scheme the public parameters(v) ie the public key and the private parameters(s) ie the private or signing key.
Let Signature_sign(s, d) -> (e) be a function that generates a secure signature/endorsement*** tag using the private parameter(s) on the provided data(d) that can be verified using the associated public parameter(v)
Let Signature_verify(v, d, e) -> VALID || INVALID be a verification function for the signature scheme that verifies for the given public verification parameter/public key(v), the data(d) being verified
Let Canonical_encode(...) -> encoded_data be a strict canonical encoding of the inputs

Setup:

Random(32) -> Sig_master
Random(32) -> Enc_master
Signature_setup(Sig_master) -> Signature_private, Signature_public
Distribute securely to all writers the tuple (Signature_private, Signature_public, Enc_master).
Distribute securely to all readers the tuple (Signature_public, Enc_master)
(OPTIONAL) Distribute to the server Signature_public if you wish for the server to verify all container updates using this scheme and not using external methods(i.e. in app authentication of the writer's session)

Writing:

Let container_data be the new container data. Let additional_data be any additional data associated with the secret container data but that is not encrypted(i.e. file name, file tagging,  and rollback mitigation measures).
Canonical_encode(additional_data, Signature_public) -> container_additional_data
Encrypt(container_additional_data, container_data, Enc_master) -> encrypted_container, container_tag
Canonical_encode(additional_data, Signature_public, encrypted_container, container_tag) -> data_to_be_signed
Signature_sign(data_to_be_signed, Signature_private) -> container_signature
Update on the server additional_data, encrypted_container, container_tag, container_signature

Reading:

Retrieve from the server additional_data, encrypted_container, container_tag, container_signature
Canonical_encode(additional_data, Signature_public, encrypted_container, container_tag) -> expected_signature_input
Signature_verify(Signature_public, expected_signature_input, container_signature) -> signature_validity
If signature_validity == True, proceed; else terminate and throw error(You have a bad copy or someone just attempted to attack you with tampered container data/metadata)
Canonical_encode(additional_data, Signature_public) -> container_additional_data
Decrypt(container_additional_data, encrypted_container, container_tag, Enc_master) -> decryption_output
If decryption_output == ERROR, terminate and throw error(You have a bad copy or there is an attack); otherwise allow access and use of the decrypted container and the container metadata.

Server verification of container update(OPTIONAL):

Unpack from the writer's updated signature additional_data, encrypted_container, container_tag, container_signature
Canonical_encode(additional_data, Signature_public, encrypted_container, container_tag) -> expected_signature_input
Signature_verify(Signature_public, expected_signature_input, container_signature) -> signature_validity
If signature_validity == True, proceed with update; else reject update attempt(You have a bad/corrupted update or someone who is not authorized tried to upload a bad container update)

Security considerations of the scheme:
This scheme protects the readers from receiving bad or tampered container data and metadata. The only entities* capable of feeding the readers bad data are the writers. We assume any writer is authorized to do anything to the container and thus malicious writers are out of scope. This scheme requires secure provisioning of both the authorized writers and readers. The key management scheme**** used for this purpose is out of scope of this scheme. If a reader is "kicked out", one needs to push out a new Enc_master secret to all writers and readers and then reencrypt the container(ie use the writing process but with the new Enc_master). This can be done lazily(ie if you are willing to tolerate the removed reader getting access to the latest version of the container before being removed) or immediately (if you wish to attempt to minimize access to container data assuming the reader did not record old container versions). If a writer is "kicked out", one needs to regenerate all secrets(Sig_public, Sig_private, and Enc_master). This needs to be done ASAP because a removed writer can attempt to race or modify the container data before the secret rotation is done. Ideally you would block the writer from attempting to read or write to the server on the server side.
* There is a monster in the room and it's called a replay/rollback attack. An attacker who can control what the users get for containers can store a previously generated container by an authorized writer. They then wait until a new container is uploaded(potentially overwriting the older one). One would expect the readers to be assured that they are given the new container. Instead, the attacker presents to the readers the old container instead. This attack is difficult to stop entirely(in the extreme case, the attacker could force a denial of service and simply refuse to serve newer container versions). Mitigations include keeping state somewhere on which version/iteration of the container should be served and verifying that information.
** Techincally speaking, if the public parameters collectively hold enough entropy(which generally speaking will be the case) and are kept secret from unauthorized attackers, you could treat it as key material and then feed it into a KDF to regenerate the encryption keys. This is nonstandard though and there's a different scheme that's easier to reason about and not need careful analysis. Notably, this method of key derivation will fail if the signature scheme used allows recovering the public parameters from a valid signature(which is a property for some signature schemes).
*** Why the term "endorsement"? I find it tends to describe the actual role of a signature a bit better sometimes. An endorsement is some publicly verifiable tag to some piece of data that can only be generated by the entity knowing the secret information needed to do so(ie the signing key). And it keeps the single letter variable s open for "signing parameter".
**** The reason why I leave the question on how to provision these keys seperate is because this will depend on your situation. If you can not trust the server at all, you will need to find a way for all the writers and readers to securely establish channels to each other, authenticate each other, and determine authorizations.

Apologies for the delay. This answer seems to only define generic cryptographic functions but not how to use them in the alternative scheme whose core idea was mentioned in one of the comments.
Further thinking about the the comment, I either don't understand some parts or some are missing. It doesn't help that I forgot to mention what writers and readers need to be able to check the validity of their S_enc without having access to the container.

Huh. I recall writing up the scheme but apparently it got eaten between my writing and posting. One sec, gonna need to retype everything again.
PS: Something ate all my formatting. The function definitions should not look like a singular blob.


Please confirm that the updated post is actually updated and not somehow rolled back magically.

Confirming, thanks! I'll need some time to parse and think about it.
